# How do I prevent the cleaning of the workspace used for Maven tycho surefire tests?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin, tycho-surefire-plugin

We have an Eclipse plugin and are using maven tycho to build it. I've now created a seperate project with unit tests and run those in the integration-test phase while building the plugin - all good. But to properly test the plugin it has to be used in a special workspace in the eclipse instance.

I don't know how I can change the workspace or prevent the workspace from gettin cleaned each time the integration-test phase begins. Currently a new workspace is created under project/target/work/data right before the test starts.

I tried to copy the workspace that I want to use in the pre-integration-test phase and even in the integration-test phase itself, but it is still cleared as soon as the actual test starts. How can I prevent the cleaning of the workspace for my plugin tests?

Answer (score 0):

Found it, just set the  property to false in the configuration of the tycho-surefire:test plugin.

Found it here: https://tycho.eclipseprojects.io/doc/latest/tycho-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#deleteOsgiDataDirectory